# Should I add my application.yml to gitignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my application.yml
There I have:

```
development: &defaults
  S3_ACCESS_KEY: "AKIfdgdfgfdgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfg"
  S3_SECRET_KEY: "fdgdflkgkldflkglfdklgfdgd"

test:
  <<: *defaults

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Should I add this to git ignore or not ?

Comment: "Do not keep production secrets in the repository, instead read values from the environment."

Comment: so I will read it from environment and set them like this: heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=THERANDOMKEYYOUGOT

Comment: @BradWerth right now I am asking should I add this file to git ignore or not=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely add this to your .gitignore. You never want to publish your access keys because people will crawl github looking for them and then use them, which could end up costing you a lot of money! If you ever post your keys accidentally make sure to change them immediately